# How does movement affect the aperture of a light cone?

Tags: special-relativity

The other day i was at a special relativity class and the teacher said that if we have a conic beam of light with an angular aperture $\theta$ then someone approaching the light source with a constant velocity V would see that the aperture is smaller than $\theta$. I didn't understand why. Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Hint (at least I think so): consider defining $\tan{(\theta/2)}$ via the length between the observer and the width of the spread, and then consider length contraction...

Comment: Check out [relativistic aberration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_aberration)

Answer (score 0):

Consider a light beam that travels out from the origin like ($w=ct$)
$$x(w) = w \cos\phi,\\
y(w)=w\sin\phi,$$
for a fixed angle $\phi$. Due to symmetry in which off-axis we call $y$, this is representative of a cone with linear angle $2\phi$ radians, or solid angle $2\pi(1-\cos\phi)$ steradians if you prefer thinking in terms of solid angle.

Under a Lorentz boost in the $x$-direction by rapidity $\rho$ this becomes
$$\begin{align}
w' &= w\cosh\rho - x\sinh\rho\\&=w~(\cosh\rho-\sinh\rho\cos\phi),\\
x' &= x\cosh\rho - w\sinh\rho\\&=w~(\cosh\rho\cos\phi-\sinh\rho),\\
y' &= y = w~\sin\phi.
\end{align}$$
The easiest way to look at this is to just trust that this is still a null ray because the Lorentz transformation preserves the norm, and look exclusively at the y-component which now looks like
$$
y'(w') = w'~{\sin\phi\over\cosh\rho-\sinh\rho\cos\phi}.$$
While I don't see any great way to simplify this geometrically we can do a small angle approximation and find that for very small angles,
$$
\phi' = e^\rho ~\phi =\phi\sqrt{1+\beta\over1-\beta}
$$
and so from this derivation you could say that this basically comes from the fact that the tangential $y$ component is being preserved while the $w$ component is being time-dilated, so $y'(w')$ gets inverse-dilated.

One then needs to carefully consider the sign of $\beta$ and $\rho$ to conclude that this describes a “relativistic beaming” for outgoing light rays as seen by an observer (outgoing radiation emitted apparently evenly in all directions gets strongly focused into the direction of motion of a moving radiator), but also that there is a double negative when looking at light rays as seen by an accelerating camera: a “Star Wars and Star Trek are wrong” effect, when you accelerate actually the distant stars appear to tilt forward in the celestial sphere around you, “crowding” into a smaller and smaller area ahead of you as you go faster and faster. Sci-fi usually shows all of the stars streaming “backwards.”